# Ejecutar PHP me arroja error 503

Tags: php

Al acceder a un archivo PHP me arroja un código de error 503 y no logro entender el porqué, esté es mi código:

```
<?php
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    if (!defined('IN_PHPBB'))
    {
        define('IN_PHPBB', true);
        $phpbb_root_path = ROOT . '/Foro/';
        $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    }
    require(ROOT . '\Foro\common.php');
    require (ROOT . '\Foro\includes\\functions_user.php');

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace, $_POST['email']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace, $_POST['pass']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace, $_POST['user']);

        $updatePass = mysqli_query($enlace, "UPDATE pcu_email SET Contra = '".hash("Whirlpool", $pass)."' WHERE Email = '$email'");

        $user_row = array(
            'username'              => $username,
            'user_password'         => md5($pass),
            'user_email'            => $email,
            'group_id'              => 2,
            'user_type'             => USER_NORMAL,
            'user_regdate'          => time(),
        );
        $user_id = user_add($user_row);

?>
```

El error es el siguiente:

> POST http://localhost/Ok/tasks/archivoPHP 503 (Service Unavailable)

Log generado en el archivo access:

> ::1 - - [29/Sep/2019:05:11:05 -0500] "POST /Ok/tasks/taskForumCreate.php HTTP/1.1" 503 2012

Log generado por mi archivo error

> Starting the 'apache24' service
>   The 'apache24' service is running.
>   mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4192:tid 504] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Mon Sep 30 15:52:18.187865 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4192:tid 504] AH00456: Server built: Dec 16 2016 18:55:21
>   [Mon Sep 30 15:52:18.187865 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4192:tid 504] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\AppServ\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/AppServ/Apache24'
>   [Mon Sep 30 15:52:18.223867 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4192:tid 504] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4100
>   [Mon Sep 30 15:52:19.270927 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4100:tid 400] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: Los errores 503 se deben debuguear mediante los logs generados en el servidor (apache, ngix, etc). ¿Puedes incluir los logs? En primera instancia es complicado, debido a que no se sabe que contiene el fichero incluido dbcon.php

Comment: Hola César, he añadido la línea que me arroja el log del archivo "access", en sí no me deja ningún error, pero supongo que el "2012" debe significar, buscaré en Internet... el `include` lo he eliminado, pues no lo necesitaba en realidad.

Comment: Los logs de apache están en el archivo error.log ¿Estas usando apache o Ngix?